# Getting previous period/same period last year attribute filter

Tags: gooddata

I'm trying to enable drill-ins for measures which are specified as "previous period" or "same period last year" of another measure.  When a drill event is fired, the intersection I get looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 'fkdljsfkdljfdkslj_pop',
    title: 'Constituents',
    header: {uri: '/gdc/md/projectid/obj/12345', identifier: 'ahdueom'}
  },
  {
    id: '54321',
    title: 'Oct/FY2018,
    header: {uri: '/gdc/md/projectid/obj/6789', identifier: 'constituentdateadded.month.short'}
  }
]
```

What I want to do is use this information to call `getValidElements` (`/gdc/app/projects/projectid/executeAfm/debug`) to get the items involved in this drill event using the first intersection element as a metric and the second as an attribute filter.  However, if I want to get the items for the previous period or the same period last year I need a different attribute filter.

Is there any endpoint that I can call to get the attribute filter which corresponds to the same period last year (in this example `'Oct/FY2017'`) or the previous period (`'Sep/FY2018'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use relative date filter in AFM to simulate previous period. Documentation is here https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/filter_visual_components.html#relative-filter-examples

If whis won't help you, could you please specify more your use case - what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I was able to get this working by finding the bucket granularity, getting the elements, and working backward to the correct element.  It works, but it's a bit hacky.